# How to pluck multiple attributes from a Backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am trying to pluck multiple attributes from a Backbone collection but it returns `undefined`.

collection

```
{
    id:1,
    name:"raju",
    age:23,
    sex:male,
    hobbies:..
}
{
    id:2,
    name:"ramesh",
    age:43,
    sex:male,
    hobbies:..
}

... //many models
```

I am trying to get multiple attributes from collection.

```
collection.pluck(["id","name","age","sex"]);
```

Expected output

```
[{//multiple attributes},{}]
```

is there any alternative way to get multiple attributes?

Comment: A jsFiddle example would be nice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @elclanrs said, [collection.pluck](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck) extracts a single attribute, you will have to use [_.map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) with a custom extraction function. Something like

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 1, name: "raju", age: 23, sex: "male"},
    {id: 2, name: "ramesh", age: 43, sex: "male"}
]);

var plucked = c.map(function (model) {
    return _.pick(model.toJSON(), ["name", "age"]);
});
console.log(plucked);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/U7p9u/

---

You could simplify this call by combining [`Collection.invoke`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) and [`Model.pick`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-Underscore-Methods)

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 1, name: "raju", age: 23, sex: "male"},
    {id: 2, name: "ramesh", age: 43, sex: "male"}
]);

plucked = c.invoke("pick", ["name", "age"]);  
console.log(plucked);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7p9u/5/

---

In a similar spirit, if your extraction function is defined on the prototype of your models:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    mypluck: function () {
        return this.pick("name", "age");
    }
});

var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M
});

var c = new C([
    {id: 1, name: "raju", age: 23, sex: "male"},
    {id: 2, name: "ramesh", age: 43, sex: "male"}
]);

var plucked = c.invoke("mypluck");
console.log(plucked);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7p9u/3/

Answer (score 3):

In the docs it says:

> "[pluck is the] Equivalent to calling map and returning a **single**
>   attribute from the iterator."

This leads me to believe that it isn't possible with multiple properties because you're basically replacing **one** item in the collection with **one** of its properties. So basically you're doing this:

```
var collect = [{a:'foo',b:'baz'},{a:'lol',b:'fur'}];

var key = 'a';
var result = collect.map(function(o){ return o[key] });
```

A possible solution would be to return an array and then flatten it, something like this:

```
result = [].concat.apply([],collect.map(function(o){ return [o.a,o.b]; }));

console.log(result); //=> ["foo", "baz", "lol", "fur"]
```

Comment: Well, that's good info but it says _"This has actually been discussed a few times before and I don't think it's a good fit."_ So you'd have to find an alternative solution. I edited my question with a solution, you just need to abstract it into your own little function.

Comment: I confuse!, is pluck able return multiple attributes?

Comment: Apparently not. Check the related questions and you'll find this https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/pull/1113

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/Lj3r85ew/

You could add `select` methods to collections and models. 
*(or name it whatever you feel is appropriate)*

```
/**
    Backbone Model Select/Multi-get -------------------------------------------
*/

Backbone.Model.prototype.select = function(props) {  
    if ( arguments.length > 1 ) {
        props = slice.call(arguments);
    }
    if ( _.isArray(arguments[0]) ) {
        props = arguments[0];
    }

    // If requesting multiple, return all props
    if ( _.isArray(props) ) {
        return _.object(props, _.map(props, _.bind(this.get, this)));
    }
    // Else, return single property
    return this.get(props);
}

/**
    Backbone Collection Select ------------------------------------------------
*/
Backbone.Collection.prototype.select = function(props) {
    if ( arguments.length > 1 ) {
        props = slice.call(arguments);
    }
    if ( _.isArray(arguments[0]) ) {
        props = arguments[0];
    }

    return _.map(this.models, function(m) {
        return m.select(props);
    });
}
```

This would allow you to select multiple properties across all models of a collection, or select multiple properties on a model.

```
collection.select('id', 'first', 'last');   // or ['id', 'first', 'last']
model.select('first', 'last');              // or ['first', 'last']
```