# extracting a list of 2 property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an object array:

```
user :[
{
  name: String,
  username: String
  }
]
```

I want to view every change either to name or username.
I found  underscore `_.pluck` only does the trick for one property  `(_.pluck(user, 'name')`
Is there another way to have the list of both values?

Comment: welcome to SO. why can't you use [`[].map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what your desired output is? Is it `[['nameA','usernameA'],['nameB','usernameB'],...]`?

Answer (score 0):

With `pluck` you can only use one property, it simply isn't made to retrieve multiple. The method you would want to use is `map`, as suggested in this relevant question + answer: [How to pluck multiple attributes from a Backbone collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121316/how-to-pluck-multiple-attributes-from-a-backbone-collection#answer-17121545)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the following output `[['nameA','usernameA'],['nameB','usernameB'],...]]`, you could use map in the following manner:

```
var myResult = users.map(function(user) {
  return [user.name, user.username];
});
```

NOTE: I changed the variable `user` to `users` to make more sense with your data.